# Something wrong with different IDE xcode and vs

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am using both Xcode and VS2017.But the code below works fine in Xcode,and get right output.But in vs, when using the function Printlist(),it stop working and run into loop:

```
Please input the number of vertexes:
5
Please input the number of edges:
6
Please input each vertex's imformation:
A
B
C
D
E
Please input the relationship between two vertexes:
A B
A D
B C
C D
B E
C E
The Adjacency Matrix you've entered is:
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
The converted adjacency list is:
(0)A->3 1
(1)B->4 2 0
(2)->4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4................
```

The program is to create an adjacency matrix and convert it to list. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. 
Thanks in advance:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define vexnum 20
#define isLetter(a)  ((((a)>='a')&&((a)<='z')) || (((a)>='A')&&((a)<='Z')))
int visited[vexnum];
typedef struct {
    char vexs[vexnum]; 
    int AdjMatrix[vexnum][vexnum];
    int n, e; //VEXNUM and EDGENUM
}MGraph;
typedef struct ArcNode
{
    int adjvex;
    struct ArcNode *nextarc;
}ArcNode;
typedef struct VNode
{
    char data;
    ArcNode *firstarc;
}VNode, AdjList[vexnum];
int GetPosition(MGraph G, char ch)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<G.n; i++)
    {
        if (G.vexs[i] == ch)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
void CreatMGraph(MGraph *G, int n, int e)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int p = 0, q = 0;
    char a, b;
    printf("Please input each vertex's imformation:\n");
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            G->vexs[i] = getchar();
        } while (!isLetter(G->vexs[i]));
    }
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
        {
            G->AdjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Please input the relationship between two vertexes:\n");
    for (k = 0; k<G->e; k++)
    {
        do
        {
            a = getchar();
        } while (!isLetter(a));
        do
        {
            b = getchar();
        } while (!isLetter(b));
        p = GetPosition(*G, a);
        q = GetPosition(*G, b);
        G->AdjMatrix[p][q] = G->AdjMatrix[q][p] = 1;
    }
}
void PrintAdjMatrix(MGraph G)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("The Adjacency Matrix you've entered is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i<G.n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<G.n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", G.AdjMatrix[i][j]);
            if (j == G.n - 1)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
void MatrixToList(MGraph G, AdjList *L)
{
    int i, j;
    ArcNode *p;
    for (i = 0; i<G.n; i++)
    {
        L[i]->data = G.vexs[i];
        L[i]->firstarc = NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i<G.n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j<G.n; j++)
        {
            if (G.AdjMatrix[i][j] == 1)
            {
                if (L[i]->firstarc == NULL)
                {
                    p = (ArcNode *)malloc(sizeof(ArcNode));
                    p->adjvex = j;
                    p->nextarc = NULL;
                    L[i]->firstarc = p;
                }
                else
                {
                    p = (ArcNode *)malloc(sizeof(ArcNode));
                    p->adjvex = j;
                    p->nextarc = L[i]->firstarc;
                    L[i]->firstarc = p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void Printlist(MGraph G, AdjList *L)
{

    ArcNode *p;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<G.n; i++)
    {
        printf("(%d)%c->", i, L[i]->data);
        p = (ArcNode *)malloc(sizeof(ArcNode));
        p = L[i]->firstarc;
        while (p)
        {
            printf("%d ", p->adjvex);
            p = p->nextarc;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    MGraph G;
    printf("Please input the number of vertexes:\n");
    scanf("%d", &G.n);
    printf("Please input the number of edges:\n");
    scanf("%d", &G.e);
    CreatMGraph(&G, G.n, G.e);
    PrintAdjMatrix(G);
    AdjList *L = NULL;
    L = (AdjList *)malloc(sizeof(AdjList));
    MatrixToList(G, L);
    printf("The converted adjacency list is:\n");
    Printlist(G, L);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably stepping on memory you shouldn't and invoking undefined behavior.  Run your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) on a Linux machine and it will tell you where.

Comment: Thanks,but I don't have linux and lack of debugging experience. Anyway, I'll think about stepping on memory I shouldn't and invoking undefined behavior：)

Comment: Don't need Linux for valgrind:  [Testing Iphone code with Valgrind](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Simulator_Valgrind.20081224.html)... Great tool, worth the effort

Comment: the function: `getchar()`  returns an `int`, not a `char`.  The posted code is not taking that into account.

Comment: the function: `createMGraph()` last parameter is `int e`  however, that parameter is not being used.  This should be corrected,

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: it is best (many examples to the contrary) to separate the struct definition from any `typedef` for that struct.  Note: most debuggers use the `tag name` of a struct to be able to display the individual fields.  So all three struct definitions should have a tag name.

Comment: this type name: `AdjList[vexnum];` would be much better written as an instance of an array of `Vnode` or `struct Vnode`.

Comment: regarding: `(!isLetter(a));`  strongly suggest you become familiar with the contents of the header file: `ctype.h`  including `isalpha()`

Comment: Thank you all! I'm working on it!

Answer (score 0):

The subscripting of parameter `L` in functions `MatrixToList()` and `Printlist()` is wrong. Consider the parameter declaration `AdjList *L`: `L` is a pointer to `AdjList`, which in turn is defined as an array of `vexnum` `struct VNode`s, so `L` is a pointer to the whole array of `struct VNode`s. Then with an expression as `L[i]->data` not the `i`th node within the array is accessed, but the `i`th array of a (nonexistent for `i` > 0) array of arrays (and with `->data` the `data` element in the first node of that `i`th array). To fix that error, you could change the parameter declaration in the mentioned functions to `AdjList L` as well as every instance of `L[i]->` in those functions to `L[i].` and call

```
    MatrixToList(G, *L);
```

and

```
    Printlist(G, *L);
```